# jQueryUI multiple themes in same page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have the following scenario: I'm using a modified JQuery UI theme (in folder tmob_theme) in a site and I need the datepicker styled differently according to date_pick theme (in same name folder). However, I have no idea why I can't make it work. I tried wrapping the textfield with a div having the date_pick class, applying that "date_pick" class or "ui-datepicker date_pick" classes directly to the textfield... but it still refuses to work and uses only the original css...

You can dload the files from here
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6134026/test_html.zip

any tips would be awesome, been combing through google for answers and have found none...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd propose you either merge the date_pick scheme into the jQuery UI theme or save the extracted datepicker related style of the date_pick theme to a separate file and import it after the jQuery UI theme.

Comment: it's supposed to work without all that sidestepping. Something somewhere is messing it up and I can't see what.